# Cusp forms with different orders at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

Let’s assume we have cusp forms $f_1,...,f_n\in S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ which they are zero at infinity with different orders. Then, how can we show that they are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the cusp forms as
$$f_i(q)=q^{c_i}g_i(q)$$
where the $c_i$ are distinct, and $g_i(0)\ne0$.

Then given a linear dependency
$$\sum_i a_i f_i(q)=0$$
consider the term $a_if_i(q)$ with minimum $c_i$ amongst the terms with $a_i\ne0$.
Divide by $q^{c_i}$ and set $q=0$ to get a contradiction.